ROS2 rclcpp understanding get_topic_names_and_types()
I came across this function get_topic_names_and_types in rclcpp recently and I have a basic question about it.
Output type is std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>. In simple term, it is as following
{
"topic_1": ["topic_type"],
"topic_2": ["topic_type"],
}

Here is one of the answers I found that explains the structure of the output by printing it for c++.
My question is, for the topic type, why we need vector of string instead of simple string?
I tried to create topic with the same name but different types. But it has thrown the exception  what():  could not create publisher: create_publisher() called for existing topic name.
So I don't understand why vector of strings as topic types?

I didn't know that you can publish multiple topic with the same name but different types.
It is why the function's second parameter's type is std::vector<std::string>. It can return multiple types of the same topic name.
I think your problem is related to this link: the link
It is seem so your problem is related to DDS. Can you change your DDS to FastDDS and try again to create a new publisher with the same name but different type.

Hello,
Yes, apparently it is possible to publish multiple types on same topic name. FastDDS is default DDS in ROS 2 (humble) installation, check here. I also verified it with wireshark, DDS vendor is eProsima Fast RTPS. I am kind of doing the same thins as mentioned in the issue.

So did you try it, could you publish it with FastDDS?

No, when I tried it for the first time, I was already using FastDDS. So it doesn't work but it should be working according to the issue on github
